# Use full ascii table to file name in linux

Tags: linux, ascii, filenames

In the Windows operating system I can use unusual characters in the file name by typing the decimal code of the character in the number pad.  This way I can access all of the characters in the character set, even if the character doesn't have a corresponding keyboard key.

Is there a way to do something similar using Linux?

Comment: Perhaps you're referring to unicode input ?. Here's how you do it on most desktop systems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the ideal solution, but you can simply use printf to embed the characters.  For example, to create a file named 'A' (octal 101), you can do:

```
$ touch "$(printf '\101')"
```

Comment: Or, `touch $'\101'` in bash.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII only covers a certain set of characters, starting at ASCII 0 to ASCII 127.  Those numbers above 127 are in heavy conflict, depending on which non-ASCII extension was used.

The general "best" solution to go with for maximum portability these days is one of the Unicode encodings.  There are a number of them, but UTF-8 is very popular.  When I say there are a number of Unicode encodings, realize that unlike different character sets, all Unicode encodings encode the same characters, they just do it with a different number of bits.  UTF-8 attempts to save a lot of disk space / memory if your stuff is mostly ASCII.

In Linux, Gnome offers a "character picker" application, called `gnome-character-map`, which will allow you to find all of the glyphs in a font for all of the Unicode characters.  Note that while it is possible to write a Unicode character, depending on the font you use, there might not be a glyph (or symbol) embedded in the font to display that Unicode character.  When you don't have something to display a particular character, sometimes a square will be drawn in the unavailable glyph's place.

I typically cut and paste characters from the character map when I need to do something special; however, there is a sequence to directly type the character in (similar to windows).  Do a Shift-Control and then type in the hexadecimal character value (which you can look up in the character map, if necessary).

Comment: Do a Shift-Control and then type in the hexadecimal character value where? I've tried VI, nautilus, gedit but nothing..